# Visual C++ cares about the array size in function arguments. Is that correct?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, cuda

When I try compiling the following (broken) code produced by CUDA's cudafe++ tool, Visual Studio throws error C2244. Is that correct behavior? GCC does not seem to care about the signature mismatch.

Code:

```
template<int Size>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(const int data[Size]);
};

template<int Size>
MyClass<Size> ::MyClass(const int data[]) {}

void func(MyClass<4> input) {}
```

Output:

```
test2.cpp(9) : error C2244: 'MyClass<Size>::MyClass' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
    test2.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'MyClass<Size>::MyClass'
    definition
    'MyClass<Size>::MyClass(const int [])'
    existing declarations
    'MyClass<Size>::MyClass(const int [Size])'
```

Comment: In an argument, `const int data[Size]`, `const int data[]` and `const int *data` are equivalent. Maybe MSVC++ have a "one declaration rule" (as a variant of [the one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) which says that "each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens"). This should not be the case for *declarations* though, only definitions.

Comment: Looks like a bug in VC++ to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is not correct.

```
int foo(const int []);
int foo(const int [4]);
int foo(const int *);
```

should all declare the same function.  Having said that, what you may want is:

```
template<int Size>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(const int (&data)[Size]);
};

template<int Size>
MyClass<Size> ::MyClass(const int (&data)[Size]) {}
```

which will *only* accept an array of the right size.